# Gradle connection timed out after update Android studio to 2.3

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-2.3

After I update android studio to 2.3, my old project is not opened in android studio shows me gradle error. And when I open a new project, that project is not build

[image]
[image]

Comment: Run `./gradlew app:build` from the command line in the project directory?

Comment: try clean. then invalidate and restart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it my self now, its very easy
Just need Edit "build.gradle.project" dependencies to 2.3.0 and edit file "gradle.wrapper.properties" , distributionUrl to "/gradle3.3-all.zip" and  sync project

Answer (score 1):

After the new update of android studio (2.3) this is a common bug.But heres the best solution to this.Once you get a message as gradle sync failed,then its as because your gradle file got bug.
the solution is go to **C:\Users\Admin.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-3.3-all\55gk2rcmfc6p2dg9u9ohc3hw9**
here you can find a zip file : gradle-3.3-all.zip

delete all contents in that and download file from https://downloads.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip

paste this in **55gk2rcmfc6p2dg9u9ohc3hw9** folder. Then restart studio.It will be working perfectly.

If you have **any other version of gradle** you can find the corresponding file in https://services.gradle.org/distributions